# Blocking IPs with htaccess and log bloat

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I set a 'deny from' in my htaccess to block certain spam bots from parsing my site. While using the code below, I noticed in my log file that I'm getting a lot of 'client denied by server configuration' and it's cluttering up the log files when the bot starts its scan. Any thoughts?

Thanks,
Steve

```
<Files *>
order allow,deny
allow from all
deny from 123.45.67.8
</Files>
```

---

I ended up going with the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} 123.4.3.4.5
RewriteRule (.*) - [F,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the conditional logging here - I think that will provide everything you need:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html

Also - if you can identify that the various bots are always coming from a specific IP address, you can block them in your hosts.allow/deny files VIA IP address or automatically using something like blockhosts or possibly mod_evasive, that way apache will never see the requests to log them.

-sean

**UPDATE:**
Are you identifying the ip addresses manually then adding them to your htaccess? that sounds painful. If you really want to do it that way I would suggest you block the ip addresses at the firewall with a drop rule OR as above in hosts allow/deny.

**SPURIOUS BROKEN RECORD UPDATE:**
Take a look at blockhosts, it can block ip addresses based on their 'behavior' & will eliminate the need for you to manually prune them out every day.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick: SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "12\.34\.25\.27" dontlog

Comment: Sorry, I jumped the gun on this one, it still seems to be logging even with the dontlog

Comment: Hmmm..  the documentation looks pretty clear - maybe 99.9% I think that could also be read as "only works on access_log" to start I would take out your deny statement in htaccess, leave the conditional logging in & see if it strips the entries from the access log but not the error log [or wait for someone to clear that up here :) ]

Comment: Hi Sean, can you elaborate on 'Spurious Broken Records'? I took a look around google and couldn't find anything. I like that idea a lot better.

Comment: hahah - I'm sorry, that's MY "spurious" comment sounding like a "broken record" - sorry to cause any confusion.  Did google at least turn up this website/post??

Comment: :) Hehe, Sean, update from the future: in 2018, no, it's not even on the 1st page of Google results, unfortunately. But if you do it quoted, then it's the no. 1 hit, indeed! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the log file to be sent to a program (aka a script).

Perhaps implement a script than just gives a periodic summary?). The rest to log file?

Comment: Is there a way for it not to write to the log file at all?

Comment: Off the top of my head cannot remember - but we had a similar problem and got a new log file started every 10 mins. A script then sorted out any problems. Also you can configure the log levels as well.